# JAVA console app to calculate the duration between two user specified dates in MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: java, date, console-application, calculator, date-difference

I have the following task:

> "Write a Java console application to calculate the duration between two dates in Years, Months and Days. The user should enter two dates as input, then the program will show the result of the difference in time between these two dates."

Does anyone have any examples of this that I can attempt to re-write? Concepts tend to stick better for me and make more sense if I'm able to write it out and see what's happening as I go. Any suggested ways to go about this? I've prowled through many Stack Overflow posts similar to my question, but none that I have came across seem to incorporate the scenario where a user inputs the two dates in question.

On a side note, I'm using Eclipse with JDK 8 if that matters.

**EDIT:** Here's my end result. Again, thank all of you so much for the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Calling in Scanner to get some user input.
import java.time.LocalDate; // Importing LocalDate
import java.time.Period;  // Importing Period

class TimeDurationCalculator {

    // Creating a main method.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("DIFFERENCE IN TIME CALCULATOR v 0.00.000.0002");
        System.out.println("BY: Matt Anderson for Grand Circus Detroit's Java Bootcamp");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("About This Program: This program will calcuate the difference in");
        System.out.println("two user specified dates in terms of months, days, and years.");
        System.out.println("");

        // Prompt for oldest date input by user.
        System.out.print("Enter the oldest date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ");

        // Creating a Scanner object
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String oldestDateString = scanner.nextLine();

        LocalDate oldestDate = LocalDate.parse(oldestDateString);

        System.out.println("You entered " + oldestDate + " for your oldest date.");
        System.out.print("Enter the most recent date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ");

        String newestDateString = scanner.nextLine();
        LocalDate newestDate = LocalDate.parse(newestDateString);
        System.out.println("You entered " + newestDate + " for your most recent date.");

        Period difference = oldestDate.until(newestDate);

        int days = difference.getDays();
        int months = difference.getMonths();
        int years = difference.getYears();
        scanner.close();

        System.out.println("Your time difference is: " + months + " Months, " + days + " Days, and " + years + " Years.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip... Focus on your problem and less on the story behind it...

Comment: At the moment, your post is basically a "gimmetehcodez" request - even if you're planning on rewriting it, there's no sign that you've already *tried* to solve the problem yourself. Additionally, we don't know what you're allowed to do - can you use Joda Time for example, or is the point that you should work out the years/months/days in your own calculations?

Comment: I'm assuming you have to write all of it from scratch and pretty restricted... so IMHO the best aproach would be reading(Scanner) the date(you did not mention the input format so you'll have to adjust) converting the input to seconds/days/months whatever suites the problem best, comparing them, then converting the difference back to the same format and output it.

Comment: This is not really a "gimmetehcodez" question. This is a "which library should I use question?" Whether they knew it or not. We shouldn't have to (re)implement the wheel all the time. There are libraries that solve this for you and it's not trivial to find them especially with Java's own Date coming up in all of your searches! On a second look: It's obviously a homework exercise...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. @Andy : I had originally written out what this was for, what I'm doing, and where I'm at but it was edited out by someone else I guess to keep things concise and to the point. This is my first post on SO as well, learning the ropes! Yes, this is actually pre-work for a Java Bootcamp that I am starting in a week. This is my final "assignment." Just looking for something to illustrate how this is accomplished since I am an absolute beginner with Java. Trying my best to grasp concepts! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have to write everything your self. Considering that you mentioned that this is an "absolute beginners" task. What I would do is read in the dates using `Scanner` then convert them to days and calculate the difference in days, then convert that difference back to "Y M D" format and print it. I'll note that I left all the "checking" out, for you to fill them in.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // create a scanner object

int year1, year2, month1, month2, day1, day2;

// promt for input
System.out.println("Enter the first date: (format -> \"Y M D\")");

// read the 1st input
year1 = scanner.nextInt(); // assuming the input is correct
month1 = scanner.nextInt();
day1 = scanner.nextInt();

// promt for input
System.out.println("Enter the second date: (format -> \"Y M D\")");

// read the 2bd input
year2 = scanner.nextInt(); // assuming the input is correct
month2 = scanner.nextInt();
day2 = scanner.nextInt();

// convert the input to days(note that the conversion is only an approximation, not every year/day has the same amount of days)
int date1 = (year1 * 365 + month1 * 30) + day1; // I'll leave the number of days in the year/month checking to you.
int date2 = (year2 * 365 + month2 * 30) + day2;

int durationdifferance = date2 - date1; // note this CAN be negative if date1 is after date2(I'll leave it to you to deside the action needed if that's true)

// convert back (this is again only an approximation)
int year = durationdifferance / 356;
int month = (durationdifferance % 365) / 30;
int day = (durationdifferance % 365) % 30;

// output the differance
System.out.println("Differance is: " + year + " " + month + " " + day);
```

Remember that you **MUST** check for the number of days in a year/month when converting...

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to give me such an awesome answer with really solid commenting. I really appreciate the effort you put into this. Your commenting in the code is helping me immensely when it comes to understanding how things come together/is structured. I'm doing my best to grasp the concepts and syntax of Java (I'm very much new). This is for my pre-work before I start a Java Bootcamp next week. Again, thanks a lot! I wish I could upvote, will certainly come back once I've earned that privilege.

Comment: Glad it helped... you can accept the answer without upvoting.

Comment: Ahh, I see now! Thanks for pointing that out to me. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Use joda [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)

Then you can calculate someones age with something like this:

```
Years.yearsBetween(mBirthDate, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)).getYears();
```

Alternatively you can use the native Java [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) but then you'll probably need to call `Date#getMillis()` and find the difference between the millis of the two dates you're interested in and then convert that to the unit that you are interested in manually (read: more error prone).

Comment: Rather than using `Years`, I'd just use a `Period` to get the difference between `LocalDate` values - but I suspect the OP is meant to write the logic for this themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
PlainTimestamp t1 = PlainTimestamp.of(1984, 12, 16, 7, 45, 55);
PlainTimestamp t2 = PlainTimestamp.of(2014, 9, 9, 19, 46, 45);
IsoUnit[] units =
    {
        CalendarUnit.YEARS, CalendarUnit.MONTHS, CalendarUnit.DAYS, ClockUnit.HOURS,
        ClockUnit.MINUTES, ClockUnit.SECONDS
    };

String out= PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(duration, TextWidth.WIDE);
System.out.println(out); 
// output: 29 years, 8 months, 24 days, 12 hours, 50 seconds
```

Comment: Giving a code-only answer which relies on a library without even identifying the library is far from ideal...

Answer (score 0):

You have the advantage of being on Java 8, which includes an upgraded date/time library modelled on the excellent Joda library that @Andy recommends. Either should be suitable.

The pre-java 8 date/time facilities suck (to coin a technical term). There is a glaring omission of Julian day in the Date and Calendar classes. Even Oracle admit this - see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

If you decide to use the old-style Java Date class, be very careful. Most locales have daylight saving, so there is one day a year that is 23 hours long (clocks go forward) and another that is 25 hours long (clocks go back). Dividing milliseconds between dates by 86400000 needs to allow for this. Just make sure you code and include unit test for these edge cases.

This may seem academic, but I once was involved in sorting out inaccurate reports of emergency vehicle response times. Because daylight saving was ignored, some responses took over an hour, and some units arrived 55 minutes before they were alerted. As you can imagine, this resulted in wildly skewed statistics. Poor time handling can have real-world implications.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on standard Java API.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        //READ TWO DAYS FROM INPUT
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Date date1= format.parse(scanner.nextLine());
        Date date2= format.parse(scanner.nextLine());
        scanner.close();

        //CALCULATE DIFFERENCE IN DAYS
        long diff = date1.getTime()-date2.getTime();
        long diffDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        diffDays = Math.abs(diffDays);
        System.out.println(diffDays);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this code and understand.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first date in this format YYYY/MM/DD: ");
        String[] date1Array = sc.nextLine().split("/");
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(date1Array[0]),Integer.parseInt(date1Array[1])-1,Integer.parseInt(date1Array[2]));
        Date date1 = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println("Enter second date in this format  YYYY/MM/DD: ");
        String[] date2Array = sc.nextLine().split("/");
        cal = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(date2Array[0]),Integer.parseInt(date2Array[1])-1,Integer.parseInt(date2Array[2]));
        Date date2 = cal.getTime();
        double difference = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/3600000;
        if(difference < 0) difference = -difference;
        System.out.println("The difference is "+difference+" hours and "+difference/24+" days");
    }
}
```